# GWT MVP, Column<MyObject, ImageResource>

Tags: java, gwt, mvp

Как мне добавить `clickHandler` к `ImageColumn` в `presenter`?

Вот мой код:

```
public interface ApplicationParamsView extends IsWidget
{
    AbstractHasData<AppParamBean> paramsTable();

    void setParamTableFocus();

    void setValueColumnFieldUpdater(
        FieldUpdater<AppParamBean, String> fieldUpdater);

    void setMoveBtnCLickDelegate(ButtonClickDelegate delegate);

}
public class ApplicationParamsViewImpl extends ResizeComposite
    implements ApplicationParamsView
{
           ...
        ImageResourceCell myImgCell = new ImageResourceCell()
    {
        public Set<String> getConsumedEvents()
        {
            HashSet<String> events = new HashSet<String>();
            events.add("click");
            return events;
        }
    };

    imageColumn = new Column<AppParamBean, ImageResource>(myImgCell)
    {
        @Override
        public ImageResource getValue(AppParamBean value)
        {
            if (value.getData() != null)
            {
                return ru.project.client.images.Images.getBundle()
                    .img0588();
            }
            else
            {
                return ru.project.client.images.Images.getBundle()
                    .img0031();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onBrowserEvent(Context context, Element elem,
            AppParamBean value, NativeEvent event)
        {
            super.onBrowserEvent(context, elem, value, event);
            if ("click".equals(event.getType()) && value.getData() != null)
            {
                Window.alert("Click imageResource");
            }
        }
    };
    imageColumn.setHorizontalAlignment(AbstractDefaultColumn.ALIGN_CENTER);
    dataGrid.addColumn(imageColumn, "Иконка");
  ...
}
 public class ApplicationParamsPresenter
extends AbstractPresenter<ApplicationParamsModel, ApplicationParamsView>
{
...
view.someclick()
{
...
}
}
```

и мне нужно добавить `clickEvent` для `Presenter`. В `presenter` мне нужно кликнуть на иконку и выполнять какие-то действия.

Comment: Тебе нужно эмулировать нажатие кнопки мыши на определённую ячейку?

Comment: Мне нужно сделать обработчик клика на ячейку. т.е. открывается страница, загружается наша таблица с такой колонкой, и при нажатии на иконку в этой колонке, должны происходить определенные действия.

Comment: Просто обработчик клика внутри создания cell-а или внутри создания column сделать не сложно, но все это во view, а мне нужно чтобы это было в presenter.

Comment: тогда засунь экземпляр `ApplicationParamsPresenter` в `ApplicationParamsViewImpl ` и передавай ему обработку нажатия на колонку